# Double/Triple 'wa' particles in a sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-が

I'm having trouble parsing the following example sentence from an online Japanese-English dictionary:

> 女性はレスリングは好まないが男性はふつうに好きだ。

Can someone explain to me how to make sense of the sentence? I'm having trouble understanding the sentence structure with the wa and ga particles thrown all over the sentence.

What other example sentences/daily conversation example where such usage of double/triple wa can be found?

Comment: Just for clarity, this sentence appears to come from Tatoeba, which means it could have been written by anyone and then a website just picked it up automatically without anyone reviewing it specifically for inclusion in a dictionary. https://tatoeba.org/en/sentences/show/147252 That doesn't impact the question directly, I just figured it would help establish more context.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm using an app that gets its data from tatoeba. Just to let everyone here know, the English sentence it's supposed to mean is "Men usually like wrestling as women do not.".. How can it be phrased in a better way, if there is any?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence puts 女性 and 男性 in contrast with each other with two は’s.

> 女性**は**レスリングは好まないが、男性**は**ふつうに好きだ。

The は after レスリング implicitly puts wrestling in contrast with other sports women might like. Replacing it with を would remove this sense of contrast.

> 女性はレスリング**を**好まないが、男性はふつうに好きだ。